# Text shadow with 0.5 value won't be displayed in Safari

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to solely display the outline of a text. Therefore my approach was to use `text-shadow`.

```
text-shadow: .5px .5px .5px black, .5px -.5px .5px black, -.5px .5px .5px black, -.5px -.5px .5px black;
```

This works for Chrome, but not for Safari - in Safari, no outline will be displayed. Changing the values to `1` will solve the problem, but the outline would be too thick in my case.

How can I solve this problem for Safari and probably other browsers?

Comment: I would also try a leading zero: `0.5px`

Comment: @RobMoll Safari 4 was released 12 years ago.

Comment: Exactly what does half a pixel look like?

Comment: @Paulie_D It's solely thinner than having 1px. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

working with 0.5px is a bad habit. try putting 1px on vertical and horizontal, and 2px on the blur factor.

or just use one shadow value:

`text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;`

Comment: _"Changing the values to 1 will solve the problem, but the outline would be too thick in my case"_

Comment: this is why I suggested to up the blur factor or combine all the shadow values